# Can't create FUNCTION in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I cannot create a function in mariadb version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

New to programming mariadb/mysql. I am moving spreadsheet data to a database.

There are no stored procedures or functions and I am using a full privileges account. I am filling in the machines table which needs to reference a store record in the stores table. A store can have several machines hence the machine is not a field in the store table.

I am just trying to get the syntax correct for making a function so I can then batch a series of numbers. It initially was a big series of SELECT and IF statements and the script choked on the IF statements. I read in someone's post that IF statements can only be used in functions and procedures. Is that true?

The error I get using 'SOURCE gen.mach.store.bat;' in interactive mode or 'mysql -u fullpriv -pabc1234 < gen.mach.store.bat' (not the real accnt/pswd) is :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4 in file: 'gen.mach.store.bat': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
  DECLARE tid MEDIUMINT;
  SET tid:=-1 ;
  SELECT tid:=id FROM stores WHER' at line 2
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

code:

```
USE SWIMAT ;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sMachine;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION sMachine( sstore MEDIUMINT , smach MEDIUMINT )
BEGIN
  DECLARE tid MEDIUMINT;
  SET tid:=-1 ;
  SELECT tid:=id FROM stores WHERE name="ChainX" AND number=sstore;
  IF tid != -1 THEN
    INSERT INTO machines(store,sn) VALUES (tid,smach);
  END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sMachine;
```

If I change Create the code to

```
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION sMachine( sstore MEDIUMINT , smach MEDIUMINT )
```

the error is near '( sstore MEDIUMINT , smach MEDIUMINT )

Is the something wrong with the function name? I have changed the name several times and altered white space all over the place. I've screwed around with semicolons. I've added a RETURNS statement at one point with a RETURN in the function.

I have posted my current working, for lack of a better word, version.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `RETURNS` part of the function signature.

Comment: I had a version that used RETURNS and it still choked. It's gotta be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a PROCEDURE instead of an FUNCTION as you are not returning a value and you do not intend to use the function within a query.

The other problem with the code is the syntax `SELECT tid:=id`, use `SELECT ... INTO` instead.

```
USE SWIMAT ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sMachine;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sMachine( sstore MEDIUMINT , smach MEDIUMINT )
BEGIN
  DECLARE tid MEDIUMINT;
  DECLARE v_found MEDIUMINT;

  SELECT id, 1 into tid, v_found
  FROM stores 
  WHERE name="ChainX" AND number=sstore;

  IF (v_found = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO machines(store,sn) VALUES (tid,smach);
  END IF;
END
$$
```

Then you can use the procedure with:

```
CALL sMachine(1,2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I'm going to have to research that SELECT syntax because it doesn't make sense to me, ... yet.

Comment: When a variable (like `v_found`) is declared, it does not have a value (=it is NULL). If the subsequent select produces a row, the variable gets a value (1 in this case). Similarily you could check if the `tid`-variable gets a value,